# FULLTEXT search with single quotes in MariaDB (leaving KEYWORD after the single quote (D'or))

Tags: mysql, mariadb, escaping, full-text-search, single-quotes

I've been searching for the answer myself for the last pas hours and testing all kind of things but I don't seem to getting closer to the answer.

I have a database with all kind of names (1.5 million +). Because of some functionality in the front-end, I need to search FULLTEXT through this data. So far so good, because it works great 99.9999% of the times. Only now one name does not came back from the search.

The name that is not searchable is for example: Data D'or

My query is looking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +(d\'or*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Nothing seems to work. I think it is because of the 'keyword' OR that is behind the single quote.
Because, when I change the name, for testing, to "Data D'ors", then it work great.

Can someone help me out with this.

Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +(d\'or*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +"d\'or*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +(d''or*)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +d\'or' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +d''or' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('+data +d\\\'or' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

etc. etc.

All came back empty

Comment: Additional, the name field is utf8mb4_general_ci. The data was saved as **Data D\'or** at first but later as **Data D'or**. Both same result.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to make this work, even if you can! You probably need to reduce the min length of a word to two and also remove the word 'or' from the stopword list and rebuild the fulltext index. However, this means that you may have lots of false positives or common words may hijack your results and relevancy scores.

Comment: Hi Shadow, yes, you are probably right, but this involves a autocomplete-ish function. Data is well checked before going in to the search. I've adjusted the innodb_ft_min_token_size to 3, which was in my opinion good for this word as well?

Also the dataset is loaded in every week from an external party, so I cannot really control the names in the database as I wish.

Comment: I've adjusted the config with:

```[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
ft_min_word_len=2```

Still nothing.

Comment: Or is likely to be stopword, as it is a common word of no consequence. Words on the stopword list are never matched for obvious reasons. If you over-optimise for this particular edge case, then you may get incorrect results for other cases. If you need really good fulltext search capabilities, then mysql is **not** the right choice!